# SQL Update query based on another table's field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

so at the moment I'm using PHP and I'm writing a SQL query. What I'm basically trying to do is update a table, set a column to 'yes' where uid column = value column in another table where name = 'beta_givebeta'

It's hard to understand. Basically update field based on another table's field value, but to find the other table's field value there needs to be a WHERE statement in that other table so it picks the right value.

It's hard to get your head around, so I apologize for the way I've wrote this.

The table users has two columns, uid and beta. Another table has two columns, name and value. I'm attempting to set beta = 'yes' WHERE uid = value, but that value from column 2 must be found with name = beta_givebeta

UPDATE:
Table 1 (t1_users) = Has two columns which are uid and beta Table 2 (t2_settings) = Has two columns which are name and value

Attempting to update the beta field which has a certain uid, but the certain uid is based on the value field in table 2 on a certain row which matches name column

As an update, this is the query I tried: UPDATE t1_users SET beta='yes' WHERE uid = (value = SELECT value FROM t2_settings WHERE name = 'beta_givebeta')

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Not hard to understand, but hard to give an exact answer without seeing table structure.  Please include the definitions for the two tables.

Comment: Provide an attempt too if you have one. You really should make an attempt before asking here.

Comment: Please explain your question a bit further with a reproducible example.

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL, you can use `join` with `update`.  This is how I interpret your question:

```
update t1_users u join
       t2_settings s
       on u.uid = s.value and s.name = 'beta_givebeta'
    set t1.beta = 'yes';
```